# Error: No module named Elasticsearch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, centos

I am running a virtual environment on Google Cloud (CentOS).

I've installed es_v as my virtual environment and followed [these instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/rpm.html) to install elastic search.

```
(es_v)$ which java
/usr/bin/java
(es_v)$ which python
/var/www/my_project/elastic/es_v/bin/python
(es_v)$ python --version
Python 3.6.5
```

I ran the configuration command and run the service:

```
sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service 
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service
```

When I am trying to ingest the data (**test.py**):

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
   }
res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
print(res['result'])

res = es.get(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1)
print(res['_source'])

es.indices.refresh(index="test-index")

res = es.search(index="test-index", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
print("Got %d Hits:" % res['hits']['total'])
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    print("%(timestamp)s %(author)s: %(text)s" % hit["_source"])
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch'
```

I tried installing elasticsearch:

```
sudo pip install elasticsearch
```

and it pointed me to the directories:

```
Requirement already satisfied: elasticsearch in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (6.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from elasticsearch) (1.22)
```

Should I include /usr/elasticsearch/ and /usr/elasticsearch/bin/ somewhere? It seems it can not find it, because I am not referring to the full path.

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to execute script with "python test.py" command.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if the python version that Scrapy is using share the same version to python-[version_number] folder the pip installed to. In my case, my Scrapy is installed on python3.8 and getting dependency from /usr/local/lib/Python3.8, but my pip after my Python update is pointing to /usr/local/lib/Python3.9. That's why Scrapy can not find the new added module 'elasticsearch'.

Solution is to specify version in command, like this:
`python3.8 -m pip install elasticsearch`